# Understanbding the syntax of Typescript hint for catch as shown in VSCode

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
Promise<void>.catch<void>(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => void | PromiseLike<void>) | null | undefined): Promise<void>
```

I am trying to understand the above hint, as far as I know I can use return statement in .catch which might not be ideal but still allowed, so why is the type Promise also what exactly does it mena when it says a promise of void type

Comment: `void` means that it return nothing (or in this case that the promise resolves with no value)